# Is it possible to X11 Forward Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu Server 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, visual-studio

I have installed Visual Studio Code on my Ubuntu Server 14.04 VM using the following method:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
umake web visual-studio-code
```

When I run ./Code, I get the following output:

```
[3796:1030/102647:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(173)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
[3810:1030/102647:ERROR:gl_implementation_osmesa.cc(22)] Failed to load libGL.so.1: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[3810:1030/102647:ERROR:gpu_child_thread.cc(163)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
Code: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server 192.168.56.1:0.0.
```

X11 Forwarding is working OK (tested using xclock) so I'm wondering if it's possible to X11 Forward Visual Studio Code?

Comment: What about this line? `Failed to load libGL.so.1: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: I've since ran sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx to fix that dependency. I now see this error: [1419:1030/130517:ERROR:gl_surface_glx.cc(347)] GLX 1.3 or later is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes it works. I just tested it.**

First off, fix your dependencies

> Failed to load libGL.so.1: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

**What I did**

I used a Virtualbox VM running Ubuntu 15.04, and VSCode. I did not have to install anything. Because it was the Desktop version, X11 libraries and such were already there.

I sshd in from an Ubuntu 15.10 workstation with `ssh -Y` and ran `./Code`. It started up just fine.

Though I did get these errors, likely because it's a remote X11 rather than directly on a graphics card.

```
[3540:1029/214400:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(173)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
[3540:1029/214401:INFO:audio_manager_pulse.cc(258)] Failed to connect to the context.  Error: Connection refused
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
[3555:1029/214402:ERROR:gl_context_glx.cc(54)] Failed to create GL context with glXCreateContextAttribsARB.
[3555:1029/214402:ERROR:gpu_info_collector.cc(41)] gfx::GLContext::CreateGLContext failed
[3555:1029/214402:ERROR:gpu_info_collector.cc(95)] Could not create context for info collection.
[3555:1029/214402:ERROR:gpu_main.cc(411)] gpu::CollectGraphicsInfo failed (fatal).
[3555:1029/214402:WARNING:x11_util.cc(1474)] X error received: serial 65, error_code 2 (BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)), request_code 154, minor_code 34 (Unknown)
[3555:1029/214402:WARNING:x11_util.cc(1474)] X error received: serial 64, error_code 2 (BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)), request_code 53, minor_code 0 (X_CreatePixmap)
[3555:1029/214402:ERROR:gpu_child_thread.cc(163)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
```

It doesn't seem to matter, VScode is working anyways.

Comment: I've since ran sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx to fix that dependency. I now see this error: [1419:1030/130517:ERROR:gl_surface_glx.cc(347)] GLX 1.3 or later is required. Is it possible to upgrade GLX to 1.3 on 14.04?

Comment: @cvandal Try running this to see what files/libs it's looking for: `strace -e trace=open ./Code 2>&1 | grep NOENT`. Once you think you know, use `dpkg -S <file>` to determine it's package. Then install it. Try again.

Comment: Cheers, Ryan! 

Turns out, thanks to your strace idea, I have installed the necessary dependencies and that when I ran glxinfo, it was actually reporting the version from my host (Windows) which was running Xming 6.9.0.31. I've since made a donation to the devs to get the latest version and I am now able to X11 forward VSCode :)

Comment: How was your performance? I tried running it in VirtualBox, Headless Ubuntu 14.04 - Host running OS-X / XQuartz. It worked, but it was so slow that it was basically unusable.

Comment: Using it from one ubuntu box to another and performance seems fine. Unnoticeable performance degradation. Trying to get it to work on a Windows box and am having trouble.

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution that worked for me if you're coming from a Windows machine:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40013437/3011683

User Frank Liu was nice enough to come back and answer his own question, which was to use [VcXsrv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/) rather than Xming. Apparently this is due to Xming not supporting some features VS code needed, but the referenced answer dosen't go into detail on why that is.

Comment: Welcome to superuser. While SO's a sister site, posts there could get deleted. It would be nice to have a little more detail on how this worked *for you* and what needs to be done, rather than a single link and a minimal explaination