# Trying to X11 forward VSCode to a windows box

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu-14.04, x11-forwarding

I've been trying to run VSCode over X11 on a Windows 7 machine. I've tested it from Ubuntu to Ubuntu using `ssh -Y hostname` and it works as expected. However, when I try to run it from my windows machine via PuTTY and Xming, it just fails. No errors given.

I've tried to run it with `strace` as suggested here...
[Is it possible to X11 Forward Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu Server 14.04?](https://superuser.com/questions/993741/is-it-possible-to-x11-forward-visual-studio-code-on-ubuntu-server-14-04)

And I get this...

```
sam@ubuntu:/usr/share/code/bin$ strace -e trace=open ./code
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)     = 3
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/proc/meminfo", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("./code", O_RDONLY)                = 3
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=7865, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=7866, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=7867, si_status=0, si_utime=12, si_stime=5} ---
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Is there anything else I can try???

Comment: I assume other programs work?

Comment: Yes. I've tried xclock and lxtask. Both work.

Comment: So I finally got around to trying it. It works for me. I use the VcXsrv X server for Windows and Cygwin SSH though. I suggest you try the X server first, because the publicly available Xming version is terribly outdated.

Comment: As @daniel-b suggested VcXsrv seems to help:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40013437/1686377